# Mobile Detection without WURFL

Tags: php, zend-framework, mobile

How could I detect the users that are on mobile/tablet/desktop **without WURFL** in ZendFramework 1.12?

PS:
ZF internal method, if possible.

Comment: So you want a ZF method for useragent detection that doesn't use the ZF useragent detection component?

Comment: Wurfl is not included in the ZF 1.12 since 1.11 Source: http://www.dotkernel.com/dotkernel/zend-framework-dropped-integration-of-wurfl-adapter/ 

Edit: as WURFL changed License to AGPL

Comment: Fair enough. In that case the only way is parsing HTTP_USER_AGENT yourself looking for particular strings.

Comment: A little example, for guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: The page you linked in the above comment gives a possible solution to grab the WURFL component from the previous Zend version. This should be fine as it's from before WURFL changed their license, and it should be forward compatible, certainly with minor point releases of ZF.

Comment: @SDC I want to miss the point when I have to configure everything the hardway. And eventually end up with a few hours wasted time. Any ways +1 for a possible solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple controller plugin (untested) that will check the useragent string:

```
class My_Plugin_Mobile extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract
{
    protected $uaStrings = array('nokia', 'android', 'ipod', 'itouch');

    public function preDispatch(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request)
    {
        if (!$request->isPost() && $request->getServer('HTTP_HOST') != 'm.example.com') {
            foreach ($this->uaStrings as $uaString) {
                if (strpos(strtolower($request->getServer('HTTP_USER_AGENT')), $uaString) !== false) {
                    header("Location: http://m.example.com".$request->getPathInfo());
                    exit;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You'll have to add some more useragents to the array but hopefully that will get you started.

Answer (score 2):

With WURFL you have ability to know mobile phone specification like:
Display width, OS and Version, Video support etc. etc.

But, if you want determine if user is on mobile phone you can use simple preg_match

```
<?php
$useragent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
if(preg_match('/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino/i',$useragent)||preg_match('/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i', substr($useragent, 0, 4)))
    header('Location: http://m.website.com');
?>
```

[Source](http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/)